# how to set up a connection without using ssh

Tags: ssh, connection, remote, openssh

hey^^ currently I'm having a problem with a compute who has ubuntu installed on it, so I wanted to use putty and get remote access. Sadly the computer is a bit of a pain in the ass and not able to install openssh after many times. Because of that I wanted to use a connection with out ssh, but I have no Idea how to do that if you don't even have openssh installed in the first place. Would be really helpfull to hear some suggestions from you guys.

Comment: While technically you could use 'telnet' for this, it is not a good idea. You better deal with SSH errors you have.

Comment: What error do you get, when you attempt to install **OpenSSH Server**? And, what version of **Ubuntu** (server)?

Comment: You need to focus on fixing this: "and not able to install openssh after many times". If you are told to jump through A hoop why choose the one that has a bottomless pit behind it?

Comment: sadly I have no internetconnection..

Comment: In the end I had to connect to the internet using a proxyserver. http_proxy=url:port. Afterwards I installed SSH with get-apt ssh and now everything works.